# what is the get_eval equivalent for selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

The following works fine in selenium-1:

```
sel = self.selenium 
sel.get_eval("window.$('body form div ul li').html()")
```

When I try to the same in selenium-2 webdriver in python, I get a error.

```
wd = webdriver.Firefox()
wd.execute_script("window.$('body form div ul li').html()")

selenium.webdriver.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: window.$ is not a function
```

How can get that jquery to work in webdriver in python?

Comment: Was able to resolve this. I was missing a return in the execute_script.

wd.execute_script("return window.$('body form div ul li').html()")

Comment: it's ok to answer your own question and accept it.  it'll be easier to find the right answer if you do this.

Answer (score 4):

In selenium1 get_eval() evaluates a script and returns the result.

When you use execute_script() you have to explicitly return the value in which you are interested.